Delete image if name contains a specific string
I have code that places a floating picture in Excel. When I make a new entry, I manually select the image and delete it so my current code can add a new image.
I noticed each time I add an image a new picture name is given in Excel. (e.g. - Picture 2, Picture 5, Picture 21, etc.)
I am trying to find the string "Picture" then delete.
Sub Delete_Pictures_ByName()
    
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim picName As String
    
    picName = "Picture "
        
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
            If shp.Name Like "*" & picName & "*" Then
                .Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub


Insert Debug.Print shp.Name after For clause, you could double check its name in the VBE Immediate Window.

I do see the shp.Name = Picture 2 in this instance, however, I'm trying to delete anything that contains "Picture" in the shp,Name.  Because the next time an image is placed the shp,Name may equal Picture 4.  The sting Picture is common each time an image is added.

How about Debug.Print shp.Name, shp.Type?

If its name is Picture 4 (no extract invisible chars), If shp.Name Like "*" & picName & "*" Then could match it.

Pardon my ignorance, but I didn't understand your last response.  Can you elaborate more please?

Big Ben you put me on the right track. I updated code line to use shp.Type = 11 instead of shp.Type = msoPicture
'If shp.Type = 11 Then'

Or msoLinkedPicture, see here

I updated code line to use shp.Type = msoLinkedPicture
    Sub Delete_Pictures_ByName()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim picName As String
    
picName = "Picture "
    
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
            If shp.Name Like "*" & picName & "*" Then
                shp.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub

